# Facebook user profile picture by username

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get facebook user profile picture by their username. 
currently i can do that by ids

eg http://graph.facebook.com/484649901695444/picture?width=700 .

Is there any other way to get the picture by username.

Answer (score 0):

The `username` field was removed with API v2.0, and querying any data via username is explicitly not possible any more for user profiles.

So no, that is not possible.

Comment: hi thanks for the response. is there any way to convert username to id

Comment: can u check this site. They are converting usernames to ids. http://findmyfbid.com/

Comment: They are most likely scraping Facebook's HTML pages directly - which is against ToS.

Comment: do you know how they are doing that ?